# I was asked to fix a bug in the search feature. I keep getting a CDbException on yii

Tags: php, mysql, search, yii

I wasn't part of the project and i'm really new to yii so finding where everything is has been a challenge.

Every time I enter something in the search bar, php keeps giving me the following error:

```
 CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'first_name' in 'where clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT * FROM `persons` `t` WHERE CONCAT(upper(first_name),' ',upper(last_name)) like :tag or upper(email) like :tag

        .tag {
    08         background-color: yellow;
    09     }
    10 </style>
    11 -->
    12 <?php
    13 $this->breadcrumbs=array(
    14     'Search'=>array('/search'),
    15     'Search',
    16 );?>
    17 
    18 
    19 <?php if (($personDataProvider->itemCount + //ERROR POINTS HERE
    20           //$galleryDataProvider->itemCount +
    21           $blogDataProvider->itemCount +
    22           $forumDataProvider->itemCount +
    23           $announcementDataProvider->itemCount +
    24           $pollsDataProvider->itemCount +
    25           $eventsDataProvider->itemCount +
    26                   $jobsDataProvider->itemCount) == 0) {                       
    27     ?>
    28           
    29 <div>
    30 
    31     <h2 style="color:#259CB1">No Results Found for <i><?=$tag?></i>.</h2>
```

For extra reference, I'll place my PersonController class here because I'm really confused by where these dataProviders are located!

```
        public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Persons');
    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}

        public function loadModel($id)
{
    $model=Persons::model()->findByPk($id);
    if($model===null)
        throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
    return $model;
}

public function loadModel2($id)
{
    $model=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('party_id'=>$id));
    if($model===null)
    {
        echo 'hi';
        exit;
        throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
    }
    return $model;
}

public function loadModel3($id)
{
    $model=Organizations::model()->findByPk($id);
    if($model===null)
        throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
    return $model;
}
```

Here is my model Persons page:

```
        public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('party_id',$this->party_id,true);
    $criteria->compare('email',$this->email,true);
    $criteria->compare('company_name',$this->company_name);
    $criteria->compare('middle_name',$this->middle_name,true);
    $criteria->compare('dob_year',$this->dob_year);
    $criteria->compare('dob_month',$this->dob_month);
    $criteria->compare('dob_day',$this->dob_day);
    $criteria->compare('nickname',$this->nickname,true);
    $criteria->compare('country',$this->country,true);


    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

I've checked the PersonController and also the search.php page but I'm not quite sure where to find the  $PersonDataProvider so I could fix this bug!

As per request, I've added the controller for actionSearch() and I see the 'first_name' (which is non existent in my db) but it's still asking me to define Person
**---------------------UPDATE------------------------**

```
    public function actionSearch()
{

            if(!isset($_GET['tag'])){                    
                Yii::app()->request->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('news/index/page/1'));
            }
            $tag = trim($_GET['tag']);

            if(empty($tag)){
                Yii::app()->request->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('news/index/page/1'));
            }

    $conditionforadmin = '';
    if(Yii::app()->user->isAdmin() == 0)
    {
        $conditionforadmin = 'and end_date > now() ';
    }                

    $personDataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Persons',array(
        'criteria'=>array(
            'condition'=>'CONCAT(upper(first_name),\' \',upper(last_name)) like :tag or upper(email) like :tag',
            'params'=>array (
                ':tag' => strtoupper('%'.$tag.'%')
            ),
        ),
        'pagination'=>false,
    )); 

    $blogDataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Blog',array(
        'criteria'=>array(
            'condition'=>'upper(title) like :tag or upper(content) like :tag',
                            //'condition'=>'upper(title) like :tag',
            'params'=>array (
                ':tag' => strtoupper('%'.$tag.'%')
            ),
        ),
        'pagination'=>false,
    ));

    $forumDataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Forum',array(
        'criteria'=>array(
            'condition'=>'upper(title) like :tag or upper(content) like :tag or upper(category) like :tag',
                            //'condition'=>'upper(title) like :tag',
            'params'=>array (
                ':tag' => strtoupper('%'.$tag.'%')
            ),
        ),
        'pagination'=>false,
    ));

    $annconditionview = Persons::model()->get_view_condition('Announcement');
    $announcementDataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Announcement',array(
        'criteria'=>array(
            'condition'=>'upper(title) like :tag or upper(content) like :tag '.$annconditionview,
            'params'=>array (
                ':tag' => strtoupper('%'.$tag.'%')
            ),
        ),
        'pagination'=>false,
    ));

            /*
    $galleryDataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Gallery',array(
        'criteria'=>array(
            'condition'=>'upper(title) like :tag',
            'params'=>array (
                ':tag' => strtoupper('%'.$tag.'%')
            ),
        ),
        'pagination'=>false,
    ));
             * 
             */

    $pollconditionview = Persons::model()->get_view_condition('Polls');
    $pollsDataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Polls',array(
        'criteria'=>array(
            'condition'=>'upper(title) like :tag or upper(content) like :tag '.$conditionforadmin.$pollconditionview,
                            //'condition'=>'upper(content) like :tag',
            'params'=>array (
                ':tag' => strtoupper('%'.$tag.'%')
            ),
        ),
        'pagination'=>false,
    ));

    $evtconditionview = Persons::model()->get_view_condition('Events');
    $eventsDataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Events',array(
        'criteria'=>array(
            'condition'=>'upper(title) like :tag or upper(content) like :tag '.$evtconditionview,
            'params'=>array (
                ':tag' => strtoupper('%'.$tag.'%')
            ),
        ),
        'pagination'=>false,
    ));

            $job_tags = SystemParameters::model()->findByAttributes(array('name'=>'job_search_tag'))->value;
            $job_tags_arr = explode(',', $job_tags);
            //$tag_arr = explode(' ', $tag);
            $tag_for_job = $tag;

            $look_for_job = FALSE;
            foreach($job_tags_arr as $v){
                //if(in_array($v, $tag_arr)){
                if($v == $tag){
                    $look_for_job = TRUE;
                }
            }
            if($look_for_job){
                $tag_for_job = '';
            }

            $jobsDataProvider = new CSqlDataProvider('Select * 
                    FROM jobs
                    WHERE upper(job_title) LIKE "%'.strtoupper($tag_for_job).'%"',array(
                    'totalItemCount'=>  Yii::app()->db->createCommand('Select count(*) 
                                                        FROM jobs
                                                        WHERE upper(job_title) LIKE "%'.strtoupper($tag_for_job).'%"')->queryScalar(),
        'pagination'=>false,
    )); 


    $this->render('search',array(
        'tag'=>$tag,
        'personDataProvider'=>$personDataProvider,
        'blogDataProvider'=>$blogDataProvider,
        'forumDataProvider'=>$forumDataProvider,
        'announcementDataProvider'=>$announcementDataProvider,
        //'galleryDataProvider'=>$galleryDataProvider,
        'pollsDataProvider'=>$pollsDataProvider,
        'eventsDataProvider'=>$eventsDataProvider,
                    'jobsDataProvider'=>$jobsDataProvider,
                    'look_for_job'=>$look_for_job
    ));
}
```

Comment: can you add your search controller code?

Comment: @kumar_v I have added my controller code.

Comment: first_name is a field of persons table?

Comment: It actually isn't. I think first_name got left behind. It's actually supposed to be company_name.

Comment: check your db what is the exact field name.

Comment: I did, it's supposed to be "company_name" instead of "first_name" yet I changed that in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per discussion in comments, you have to change the code as below:
In controller:

```
$personDataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Persons',array(
        'criteria'=>array(
            'condition'=>'company_name like :tag or upper(email) like :tag',
            'params'=>array (
                ':tag' => strtoupper('%'.$tag.'%')
            ),
        ),
        'pagination'=>false,
    ));
```

Then in model:
Comment out unwanted condition as we are checking those two fields in condition sections already.

```
$criteria->compare('party_id',$this->party_id,true);
   // $criteria->compare('email',$this->email,true);
   // $criteria->compare('company_name',$this->company_name);
    $criteria->compare('middle_name',$this->middle_name,true);
    $criteria->compare('dob_year',$this->dob_year);
    $criteria->compare('dob_month',$this->dob_month);
    $criteria->compare('dob_day',$this->dob_day);
    $criteria->compare('nickname',$this->nickname,true);
    $criteria->compare('country',$this->country,true);
```

Comment: Although your answer was helpful and makes sense. I'm still having an error somewhere along the CActiveRecord area saying somewhere that:

Property "Persons.first_name" is not defined.

Why is it looking for it still? Where do you think it's calling this ?

Comment: Are you using first_name and last_name in your controller somewhere else? Or in view file? If you found, just comment those line.

Comment: I found the first_name under the views section. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check that the 'first_name' column exists in the database. If it does check the model rules() to see if there is a rule about it or check if 'first_name' is defined as public property for that model class.

Comment: Thanks, I found it inside the views under _person ahah. It was really annoying to find.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Look like there is no 'first_name' column in your database as you show in your model.

```
$criteria->compare('party_id',$this->party_id,true);
$criteria->compare('email',$this->email,true);
$criteria->compare('company_name',$this->company_name);
$criteria->compare('middle_name',$this->middle_name,true);
$criteria->compare('dob_year',$this->dob_year);
$criteria->compare('dob_month',$this->dob_month);
$criteria->compare('dob_day',$this->dob_day);
$criteria->compare('nickname',$this->nickname,true);
$criteria->compare('country',$this->country,true);
```

Comment: There isn't a first_name column in the database and there also isn't a first_name inside that block of code you posted. I'm trying to look for where to find the sql statement that's not being executed.